# Combine or average multiple lines/edges into single line in image

Tags: r, image-processing, imagemagick

I have extracted from a series of images their edges using magick in R.
Individual results look as follows:

[image: individual edges]

What I am trying to do, is combine similar lines, into a single line.
For example, the first two lines are fairly similar in the region that they encompase, and one could take something like 'the average' between both.
There are also some clear similarities between the third and fourth image.
I have hundreds of these.

If I just add all images together (simply summing the matrices that represent them), I get a lot of clutter:

[image: combined edges]

But I can still make out some regions.

Ideally, I am looking for a solution with R.

Edit:

Goal. So, what I have here are the results from some spatial models based on the lat and lon of some populations. I have hundreds of binary features for some 90 places. I fitted a 2 dimensional GP for each feature, and the calculated the predictions for a grid of points covering a square area encompassing all points. The goal is to find general dividing lines that separate groups of points.
This is what the original predictions look like:

[image]

Edit 2:

Here are some matrices in rds format:

Original GP predictions:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1785BBcGKZ2TMLBKbcXKLlcrLue_VJl0O/view?usp=sharing

Extracted edges: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OUQy6rsP5Mxmf18TXwvoZ8O7MS7Hom3t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Interesting question. You might consider providing the four input images *separately* and without axes/annotation and extraneous stuff so that folks can experiment without needing to slice and dice first. You might not, but it's a thought

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but I don't think this problem is very well specified. 'Something like the average' is a pretty vague instruction to give to a computer. How would a program know which lines you felt were similar enough to be averaged? Even in the first two images, there are thousands of ways you could map the pixels from the first line onto the pixels of the second line to generate an average. You might be better averaging the original images and getting outlines from that.

Comment: what's the input, what's the goal? you described your approach, not the givens or the goal.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can provide the matrices, what's the correct way to share that data here?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, the problem has to steps. First, finding which images describe a similar shape, and then adding those together. By 'average' I was thinking something like the line which is equidistant to both lines. If two images are two concentric circles, then the 'average' would be the circle between them.

Comment: I understood what you meant, but that is not a trivial problem to solve in the general case. If you want to group the images by similarity, then you may need a machine learning approach here.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have edited the question with some more information on what the goal is.

Comment: I just mean 4 separate PNG images without axes, or surrounding background.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Sorry if I'm not being clear. I want to find general recurring areas in those heatmaps. For example, in the heatmaps I show, there is a general split between left of 0.5 and right of 0.5. I want to find that dividing line. But there are also other patterns, like a general separation of the bottom right corner.

Comment: so... this is really supposed to be a binary classifier?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes. The heatmaps are probability of the feature being present or not, and I have thousands of these. I need the recurring areal patterns.

Comment: if two maps are of the *same area*, you could just add them (take average). -- perhaps also look into "support vector machine", an algorithm for statistical classification. as is, it can do linear classifications (a (hyper)plane "separates" the two classes)

Answer (score 0):

It is I think all on how you define clutter and what you expect to see.

Lets make some very small example of "image" matrixes having 2 "colors"

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), 3, 3)
m2 <- t(apply(m1, 2, rev))
m3 <- t(apply(m2, 2, rev))
```

Let us see how they look like

```
image(m1)
```

[image]

```
image(m2)
```

[image]

```
image(m3)
```

[image]

Then it is the call you have to make on what you define clutter or not, but let us add up the values in the matrices

```
all <- m1+m2+m3

image(all)
```

[image]

We see now 3 colors, darkest was present in all images (most images) and lightest color in none of the images (least images).

To remove noise it would be a matter of setting matrix values below a certain threshold to zero to remove the clutter and if you prefer you could convert it (based on thresholds) back to a binary matrix

Comment: This works well in the case of overlap between edges, but does not solve the problem where the edges lie close to each other, but do not overlap, like in the case of many concentric circles. I want to take those concentric circles and make a single 'mean' circle out of them.

Comment: Do I understand now correctly that if we assume 4 3x3 matrixes with each one having in one but different corner 1  dark dot, you want in the final output 4 dots (each on one corner)?

Comment: If we have 2 3x3 matrixes, one with a line on the first column, and the other with a line in the third column, I want to get a matrix with a line in the middle column. In the case you describe I would want to get a matrix with one single dot in the middle, I think.

Comment: In that case, you might like to dilate the lines in order to encourage them to touch, then take the medial axis to skeletonize them... maybe.